# Verify TCP connection is from same machine by MAC address

Tags: c, linux, sockets, mac-address

Please don't criticise the solution. It's not my design and yes, it sucks.

On a computer running Linux, and using C, we need to verify that a TCP connection made to a process is from the same machine. Doing it by IP address is problematic since the OS is generating two IP addresses and the process only knows one. Anyway, verifying by IP address is a bit poor.

We want to do the verification by comparing the "remote" MAC address to the local MAC address. We already get the local MAC address. All I need to know is how to get the "remote" MAC address. It's in the packet that gets sent when forming the connection (and in all subsequent ones too). How do we drag it out of the ethernet layer?

Before anyone says this again, I KNOW you cannot get the MAC address of the remote host if it's not on the same subnet/LAN. That's fine. Presumably we'll get something like 00:00:00:00:00:00 and since that is different to the local MAC address it will be different - just what we want.

--

So, to summarise, we have a TCP connection socket fd, we've received a data packet, how do we then find the MAC address of the remote host, the MAC address that was in the packet's header?

Comment: Are you trying to determine identity? because I can think of several better ways to do so than by using a spoofable MAC address

Comment: If the local packets are coming in with two different IP addresses, how do you know they're not going to come in with two different MAC addresses? If some packets are coming through the loopback adapter, they don't go anywhere near the hardware and so won't have a MAC address at all (IIRC).

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that it's possible to bind the server to the loopback interface only? In that case only clients on the same machine can make a connection (and they must use 127.0.0.1 as remote address), it is not possible to connect from another machine.

Comment: Of course you said this isn't your design, but make sure everyone is aware that if this is for security reasons, then it's not really doing much. It's easy to change MAC addresses at will.

Comment: Hasturkun: Yes I know which is why I said "First of all, please don't criticise the solution. It's not my design and yes, it sucks". Mr Mior: I know. I'm no expert but I think we might be safer on the grounds that the SYN/ACK response to someone spoofing the MAC address shouldn't go anywhere near the spoofer - but like I say I'm not an expert. And I will be doing what I can to raise awareness, but I doubt it will have much effect. Bart: Good idea. I'll suggest it and see what happens.

Comment: In response to all answers below, thanks. Just out of technical curiosity though, is there no way to get it from the packet header, say using an ioctl() call or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are not trying to tell remote machines apart, but to use the idea that the source and destination MAC would match on traffic sent from a machine **to itself** in order to allow only local traffic.

This seems rather roundabout, and has been pointed out, insecure.

A somewhat better idea might be to have the TCP client listen only on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) and not on INADDR_ANY.  Or go a step further and use a unix-domain socket instead of a TCP one (a common method used by X servers today to prevent the possibility of remote connections)

Comment: The piece of software in question is a UPNP server and I suspect they've wrapped the control request we want to verify in UPNP and so are having it come in on the same INADDR_ANY socket listener. PLEASE don't comment on how stupid that is. I know.

However maybe we could do a further hack and send the UPNP request to 127.0.0.1 even thugh we've identified the UPNP server on a different IP address.

Comment: Which end are you in a position to modify, the client or the server?

Comment: Both. The problem is that because they've wrapped the control request in UPNP (I was right - unfortunately) it'll be using all the other UPNP infrastructure on both sides and unwinding that is going to be very complicated and involve the architects etc. etc. etc. :(

The quick easy solution is just to grab the MAC address for the remote end of the connection and do a comparison. I'm starting wheels turning to use your idea, but it will take weeks - if I can even persuade them to consider it - and we are already weeks behind where we want to be.

Comment: Modify the server to listen on both tcp and unix sockets but only accept special operations from the later.  Modify the (local) client to connect on the unix socket.

Comment: Unfortunately the client uses the same UPNP code to connect to other machines on other hosts and that sort of customisation isn't possible - the client has no idea of the address - it identifies the server by UUID. Putting that sort of customisation lower down the stack would be a bit of a nasty hack, changing nice generic UPNP code so it has special cases for just this one case. Using the loopback address is still the best idea.

Answer (score 3):

The MAC address of a live same-subnet TCP connection will almost certainly be in the ARP cache.

On Linux, you could examine the ARP cache by looking in `/proc/net/arp`. Here is what it looks like on my Ubuntu box:

```
aix@aix:~$ cat /proc/net/arp
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
10.0.0.32        0x1         0x2         00:1e:4f:f5:be:dc     *        eth0
10.10.10.1       0x1         0x2         00:1f:6c:3e:02:e3     *        eth0
```

There's probably some callable API that you could use to get to the same data if you're averse to parsing the pseudo-file.

Comment: What if there's a bridge present?

Comment: Unfortunately only remote IP addresses are listed in this file. I guess we could try confirming that the source IP address is NOT listed in this file, but I don't think that's any guarantee that the connection is coming from a remote host.

However it does occur to me that we could try modifying the code to scan all the IP addresses used on the box and check if we match any of them, but that's a lot more code and work and difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

How about configuring a firewall (internal or external) to block or MAC-filter external traffic on the port in question?

Comment: See my comment on your earlier answer. The port is shared with all other UPNP traffic. I believe that we want external access to this process although it's mainly an internal component of the overall system.

Comment: Configure a firewall to redirect external traffic to a different port and listen on both?

Answer (score 0):

A loopback connection (whether it's over the loopback interface or some other interface) it not routed over any ethernet device and therefore **does not have a MAC address** associated with it.

I suggest you just use `getsockname` and `getpeername` to get the local and remote IP address and compare that they are equal. That will work without any a priori knowledge of the configured IP addresses of your system.

Further, if you want to be IPv4/v6 agnostic, you could use `getnameinfo` with the `NI_NUMERIC` flag to convert both addresses to numeric string representations and `strcmp` them.

Comment: That's what we are already doing and it doesn't work. getsockname and getpeername are returning different IP addresses. I clearly stated in the question that there are two IP addresses and somehow we can only find out about the one at the local end of the connection. Hence we are led to believe that the connection is from a different machine because we don't know the second one at the other end of the socket is actually the same machine.